# Won't use my Sql database

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

Hey i have some trouble with my SQLite database, when i have closed my app and i then try to save my values it gives me an error in my logcat.

The app was supposed to store the data when i close the app with sharedPreferences, when i reopen the app is supposed to send data from my main class and when i push the stop button the data should have been saved to my SQLite database.

Why is this not possible?

It is possible to do this without closing the app.

Thanks for your help.

My main class:

```
public class Main extends Activity{

Button bStart, bStop;
TextView tvView;
Spinner spinner1;
boolean stopValue;
int startkilometer;
String date;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    bStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStart);
    tvView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvView);
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);


    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);



    stopValue = pref.getBoolean("stopper", false);
    startkilometer = pref.getInt("startkm", 0);
    date = pref.getString("datoen", "");



    date = getIntent().getStringExtra("datoen");
    startkilometer = getIntent().getIntExtra("startkm", startkilometer);
    stopValue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("stopper", stopValue);


    if(stopValue == false){
        bStart.setText("Start");
        bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent start = new Intent("com.uniqueapps.runner.START");
                startActivity(start);
            }
        });
    }

    if(stopValue){
        bStart.setText("Stop");
        bStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent stop = new Intent("com.uniqueapps.runner.STOP");
                stop.putExtra("startkm", startkilometer);
                stop.putExtra("datoen", date);
                startActivity(stop);
            }
        });
    }

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("stopper", stopValue);
      editor.putInt("startkm", startkilometer);
      editor.putString("datoen", date);
      editor.commit();

    super.onPause();
}
```

My stop class:

```
public class Stop extends Main implements OnClickListener {

Button bStop;
EditText sqllocations, kilometer;
int startkilometer, slutkilometer, kortekm;
String locations;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.stop);
    bStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bstopTur);
    bStop.setOnClickListener(this);
    sqllocations = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.locations);
    kilometer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.drovenKilometer);


    startkilometer = getIntent().getIntExtra("startkm", 0);
    date = getIntent().getStringExtra("datoen");

    sqllocations.setText("Unknown");
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(v.getId()){

    case R.id.bstopTur:

        String locations = sqllocations.getText().toString();
        slutkilometer = Integer.valueOf(kilometer.getText().toString()); 
        int kortekm = (slutkilometer - startkilometer);

        try{

        KilometerSQL entry = new KilometerSQL(this);
        entry.open();
        entry.createEntry(date, kortekm, locations); ----> Line 60
        entry.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         Intent menu = new Intent("com.uniqueapps.runner.MENU");
            menu.putExtra("stopper", false);
            startActivity(menu);
            break;
    }
}

}
```

My KilometerSQL:

```
public class KilometerSQL {

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "date";
public static final String KEY_KILOMETER = "kilometer";
public static final String KEY_LOCATIONS = "locations";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Kilometerdb";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "kilometertable";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_KILOMETER + " INTEGER, " +
                KEY_LOCATIONS + " TEXT NOT NULL);"


                );
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }


    }

public KilometerSQL (Context c){
    ourContext = c;
}

public KilometerSQL open(){
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String date, int kortekm, String locations) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_ROWID, date);
    cv.put(KEY_KILOMETER, kortekm);
    cv.put(KEY_LOCATIONS, locations);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv); ----> Line 74
}

public String getData() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String [] columns = new String []{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_KILOMETER, KEY_LOCATIONS};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result = "";

    int iDate = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iKilometer = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_KILOMETER);
    int iLocations = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_LOCATIONS);

    for (c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext()){
        result = result + c.getString(iDate) + " " + c.getString(iKilometer) + " " + c.getString(iLocations) + "\n";
    }

    return result;
}


}
```

My Logcat:

```
10-01 13:54:25.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(3199): Error inserting kilometer=30 date=null locations=Unknown
10-01 13:54:25.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(3199): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: kilometertable.date may not be NULL (code 19)
10-01 13:54:25.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(3199):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLastInsertedRowId(Native Method)
10-01 13:54:25.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(3199):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteConnection.java:782)
10-01 13:54:25.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(3199):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLastInsertedRowId(SQLiteSession.java:788)
10-01 13:54:25.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(3199):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeInsert(SQLiteStatement.java:86)
10-01 13:54:25.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(3199):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1469)
10-01 13:54:25.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(3199):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
10-01 13:54:25.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(3199):     at com.uniqueapps.runner.KilometerSQL.createEntry(KilometerSQL.java:74)  
10-01 13:54:25.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(3199):     at com.uniqueapps.runner.Stop.onClick(Stop.java:60)
10-01 13:54:25.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(3199):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
10-01 13:54:25.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(3199):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
10-01 13:54:25.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(3199):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-01 13:54:25.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(3199):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-01 13:54:25.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(3199):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-01 13:54:25.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(3199):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-01 13:54:25.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(3199):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-01 13:54:25.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(3199):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-01 13:54:25.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(3199):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-01 13:54:25.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(3199):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-01 13:54:25.865: E/SQLiteDatabase(3199):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It is all written in logcat log...

Comment: `kilometertable.date may not be NULL` here is your problem

Comment: it is not saved then maybe?

Comment: Well, does your code save a non-NULL value in the `date` column?

Comment: Maybe this is a stupid question, but what can i do to that error kilometertable.date? That line is not in my code, is the date not send to the stop class or why am i getting this error?